# Unable to Install SQL 2017 CU 28

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, patching, cumulative-update

I am in the process of upgrading our SQL 2017 servers to the current CU. I have ran across two systems that won't allow me to apply the update. In the SQL installer, I see below text when I click on the SQL Instance name.

> The version of SQL Server instance MSSQLSERVER does not match the version expected by the SQL Server update. The installed SQL Server product version is 14.0.3381.3, and the expected SQL Server version is 14.0.1000.169."

[image: Installer Screen]

I am unsure where the installer pulls the version info from. I have compared the registry against a couple of other systems and nothing is standing out as being incorrect, so not sure where it is pulling the 14.0.1000.169 value for the "expected sql version". I tried removing the previous CU so I could reapply it, but it didn't appear that it removed fully as it was still in the add/remove programs screen. Everything I have found online points to older versions where people were trying to install CUs on top of the wrong Service Packs, which doesn't apply in this case since SQL 2017 doesn't have service packs.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `14.0.3381.3` is CU23. `14.0.1000.169` is RTM.  It sounds like _something_ is awry here. Is it possible that the CU23 install did not go smoothly on this server? You should be able to find the CU23 install logs at `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Setup Bootstrap\Log\<datetime of CU install>\Summary_<Instancename>_<Datetime>.txt`

Comment: CU28 is 14.0.3430.2, which is what I am trying to apply. 14.0.3381.3 is CU23. @@Version shows - Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU23) (KB5000685) - 14.0.3381.3 (X64)   Feb  9 2021 12:08:50   Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2019 Standard 10.0 <X64> (Build 17763: ) (Hypervisor) .

Comment: check out that `Setup Boostrap` folder. There will be a folder for each successful or failed install. It has everything from the original service install to every CU. Wading through the summary.txt files can be a lot, but the CU23 install logs may be enlightening. Plus any failed installs since then.

Comment: Maybe is because you are installing a different language. Check your current language

Comment: I looked through the bootstrap logs and didn't see anything that jumped out at me. I also checked the language and everything appears to be set for English. Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution below

We found that there is an instance mapping for Report Server that maps default instance name (MSSQLSERVER) to SSRS instance ID:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names\RS
MSSQLSERVER REG_SZ SSRS

[image]

This causes the SQL setup to fail to patch the default instance.

Recommendation/Resolution

Deleting the 'MSSQLSERVER REG_SZ SSRS' registry key at 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names\RS' allows SQL setup to successfully patch the default instance. Upon further investigation
Furthermore, we confirmed that this key should not exist as it implies the presence of a second SSRS 2017 instance which is not possible as SSRS 2017+ does not support multiple instances on the same server.